# IE10 iFrame loads page but doesn't display

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I am trying to set up an iFrame to show a form from another domain within our company.  And testing it in Chrome or Firefox works just fine.

The problem is, for IE 10, instead of showing the form, the browser is instead showing a blank page in the iFrame.

I've broken it down to a very simple test.html on my desktop.  The Developer's Tools show that the network call not only works - but it registers loading files that are being included in the page I'm trying to call.  I've even seen the debug statements in the form's javascript firing, and ajax calls running.  But the iFrame is still showing blank.

I have hunted and searched and cannot figure out how to make this work.

The calling page has:

```
<!doctype html>

...

<DIV><iframe height="400" width="100%" src="http://my.domain.com/myForm?userName=clicky&email=cMcTesterton@domain.com"></iframe></DIV>
```

The called page has as its first two lines:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!doctype html>
```

Which, of course, changes to simply

```
<!doctype html>
```

I am using URL binding, so there isn't an extension to speak of.
I have gone into IE's `Internet Options` -> `Security` -> `Custom level ...` -> `miscellaneous` to enable `Launching Programs and files in an IFRAME` and `Navigate windows and frames across different domains`

I can't even figure out what else to look for.  It especially confuses me that according to the console, it has to be reading the page I'm trying to bring up.  It just isn't showing it.

Comment: Is the calling page (with the iframe) located in the `http://my.domain.com` domain?

Comment: @bastos.sergio No, it is not.  It is on another domain within our company.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe - As Bastos.Sergio is implying, this can cause an issue: http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin So ... it will load up the cross-domain page, run its javascript, etc etc etc, but it just won't show it?

Comment: @WolfmanJoe Not sure, I'm afraid, it's been a while since I've dealt with that, but it could be an issue.

Comment: Make sure you're not running into a `same origin policy` problem. Try putting the calling page on the same domain as the page referenced by the iframe, and check if the problem goes away.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe, This could be a problem, if you're using javascript to show the content as javascript is blocked from running, for instance.

Comment: @bastos.sergio No, the javascript is running just fine.  The problem is that the iFrame is blank - but all the javascript is running fine.  And yes, if I put the calling HTML on the same domain, then it works fine.  So I can run all the javascript I want from another domain, but I cannot show html from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure, either (1) your site `http://my.domain.com` or (2) the page located in the site `http://my.domain.com` to send out the `X-Frame-Options` meta tag.

The `X-Frame-Options` meta tag is basically a hint to tell the browser that it's safe to render the page inside an iframe.

**Option 1** - configure your webserver to send out the `X-Frame-Options` meta tag

```
<system.webServer>
  ...

  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM http://my.otherdomain.com" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

  ...
</system.webServer>
```

**Option 2** - configure your page (the one referenced at `src="http://my.domain.com/myForm?userName=clicky&email=cMcTesterton@domain.com"`) to send out the `X-Frame-Options` meta tag

```
<head>
    <meta name="X-Frame-Options" content="ALLOW-FROM http://my.otherdomain.com">
    ....
</head>
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: I am trying to google that and it says web.config is an ASP .NET configuration file?  Are you giving me an ASP .NET answer, or is this something more universal that I'm missing?  Because I'm afraid I'm not using ASP .NET.  (but hopefully this helps someone who is.)

Comment: I'm giving you a configuration for an IIS server app (IIS normally uses ASP.NET). Irregardless, you must configure your web server, to send out the meta tag `X-Frame-Options`. Please check out the link that I posted in my answer to learn how to configure other web servers.

Comment: Option 2 didn't work, sadly - but I'm looking into doing option 1 for our server.  I won't be able to test it soon, though, cause changes to the config has to run through the admins.  But thank you very much!

Comment: Hum, strange that option 2 didn't work--it's functionally equivalent to option 1. You should test out option 1 before pushing it out to your admins though.

Comment: test it out on a development server (one you can manage as needed)